# npm-пакеты не устанавливаются

Tags: npm

[image: Скрин терминала]

Не устанавливается никакой из npm-пакетов: ни sass, ни yo code, ни много других. Однако npm create react-app работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: добавил строку export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH" в скрытый файл ~/.zshrc в документах